# 数値を特定の範囲に収める

Tags: ruby

標準クラスか`active_support`に数値を特定の範囲に収めるメソッドが用意されていたと思うのですが、名前を忘れてしまいました。

具体的にはこのような動作をするメソッドです。

```
class Numeric
  def within(min,max)
    [[min, self].max, max].min
  end
end
```

これを使って

```
3.within(1,5)
#=> 3
-1.within(1,5)
#=> 1
6.within(1,5)
#=> 5
```

単なる私の記憶違いかもしれませんが、ご存知のかたおられますか？

Comment: [Numeric#clamp](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10594)として提案されている状態なので、少なくとも標準にはまだ存在しないはずです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。恐らく提案を見たのと記憶が混ざってしまっていたようです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@h2so5 さんのコメントにあるように、まだメソッドはないようです。

- Ruby: #4574  :[Numeric#within](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4574)
- Ruby: #10594 :[Numeric#clamp](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10594)

提案部分から疑似実装できますね:

```
class Numeric
  def clamp( range)
    [[range.begin, self].max, range.end].min
  end
end
```

出力:

```
234234234523.clamp(0..100)       # => 100
12.clamp(0..100)                 # => 12  
-38817112.clamp(0..100)          # => 0
123456.clamp(0..Float::INFINITY) # => 123456
12.clamp('a'..'z')               # => error
```